# BT issues - Not Discoverable

Tags: windows, bluetooth, windows-11

as the title ays. it's a brand new board, installed it a few days ago (basically it's a new build) thought I'd pair my Elite 2 controller but no luck. when I click pair, it's only showing me 2 devices my Nvidia shield and an Unknown Device. When I click on unknown then it's my soundbar but neither connect.
Here's what I've done so far -

1. Unistalled BT drivers/devices under Device Mananger.
2. Updated the BT Driver from Asus Website, at first when I click on update it said 'best driver already installed' but when I do it manually and select the driver then it installs it and I can see the driver number changed.
3. Updated BIOS
4. Installed the Chipset software and just installed everything there.
5. Stopped and Restarted Bluetooth Services (There's 3 of them under Services, Bluetooth Support, Bluetooth Audio and another Bluetooth User) - Set as Automatically and tried Manual as start up type.
6. Power Flush - Shut down, unplugged, held power for 30 seconds.
7. Resinstalled Windows from 11 to 10 and then back to 11. thinking if it's a Windows 11 issue.
8. Started Network Discovery and Devices
9. Run the Troubleshooter and it came back with 'Fixed' for BT Radio but still not working.
10. I also unticked the 'save power mode' on the bluetooth device.
11. Followed a video which showed to run commands ( dism /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth & sfc /scannow) but no issues found.
12. About 10-15 times trying to pair the controller it does eventually pop up - sometimes it fails (Unable to connect) but eventually when I do find the controller, it connects but the controller is still flashing i.e. not connect as it should be a solid light.

So then I thought it's a problem with the controller so on another laptop running Windows 11, If I click on Add Device, I can find like 8 devices pretty much within seconds, I paired the controller to my Nvidia Shield and it worked really fast, I can find the controller on my phone. I connected the controller to the laptop and I played for a minute. I then tried connecting to a Bluetooth Speaker and I'm getting the same thing on my pc. I can find the speaker on the Phone and Laptop without issues.
I've gone through 20 videos and website but can't get it to work. Tried to send and recieve files but that too doesn't work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Unable to discover any devices, when trying to add device, it shows me 2 devices but neither of them connect. Tried pairing a Controller and a Bluetooth Speaker those do not show up. Checking on another laptop, I can see both along with many other bluetooth devices. Pretty much ran 12 different points (mentioned above) to fix this but no luck.

Comment: if it's brand new it's still covered under warranty. Contact customer services to check if this is a common issue, if it's not, get a replacement.